# Как исправить TAB-отступ в Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

При нажатии TAB в PyCharm ставится полу-отступ(2 пробела), а раньше был полный отступ(4 пробела). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно ваш вопрос [уже задали разработчику](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206332339-Tabs-and-Indents-are-2-spaces-despite-setting-at-4-spaces)

> 1. "Settings | Editor | Code Style" -- try disabling "Detect and use existing file indents for editing"